# Cannot add Python Interpreter in Aptana Studio: SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference."

Tags: aptana, pydev

I have Python 2.7 installed on my PC.  I have Aptana Studio 3 installed.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled everything in every ordder you can imagine.  I have rebooted countless times.  I still can not get Aptana to recognize that I have Python 2.7 installed.

Whe I try to Autoconfig I get:

"See error log for details.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference."

When I try to add new I browse to:  C:\Python27\python.exe and get this error.

"See error log for details.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference."

I am running all of this on a Win 7 64 bit machine.  Both Apyana and Python are 64 bit versions.

I have this all running on two other machines with no issue.

Thanks for any help anyone can give me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, reinstalling Aptana into a path without spaces or special characters resolved.

**Path that was generating errors:**

C:/Users/Bruno & Lu/AppData/Local/Aptana Studio 3

**Way it works now:**

C:/Aptana

Comment: The error was the result of the "&". Though the method you described is not wrong (it should resolve the error), you state that it works because of the lack of "spaces or special characters".